# Why Link from React Router Dom does not refresh when go back?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a simply pagination for my app, and everything is working fine until I am not pressing a back button. Pagination works fine but does not refresh on back or forward buttons.
Component is just not rerendered. How to achieve this?

```
<Route exact strict path="/page=:id" component={Home}></Route>
```

My states:

```
const [meetings, setMeetings] = useState([]);
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(3);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(+match.params.id || 1);
```

Pagination function to render new Array

```
const paginate = (items, pageNumber, pageSize) => {
    const startIndex = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;
    return _(items)
      .slice(startIndex)
      .take(pageSize)
      .value();
  };

  const paginatedMeetings = paginate(meetings, currentPage, pageSize);
```

and simply render buttons

```
<Pagination
        itemsCount={meetings.length}
        pageSize={pageSize}
        currentPage={currentPage}
        onPageChange={handlePageChange}
      />
```

Pagination component:

```
const Pagination = ({ itemsCount, pageSize, onPageChange, currentPage }) => {
  const pagesCount = Math.ceil(itemsCount / pageSize);
  if (pagesCount === 1) return null;

  const pages = _.range(1, pagesCount + 1);

  return (
    <div>
      {pages.map(page => (
        <StyledLink as={Link} to={`page=${page}`}>
          <StyledButton
            active={page === currentPage}
            onClick={() => onPageChange(page)}
            key={page}
          >
            {page}
          </StyledButton>
        </StyledLink>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely your component isn't remounting, so its state stays the same as what you had it previous. since match is a prop, you need to use `useEffect` to run an effect when the match parameters change, and update your local state. Something like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setCurrentPage(props.match.params.id);
}, [props.match.params.id]);
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that I wouldn't avoid that but yeah it works, you should mention for others that we need to use 'useRouter' hook and +match.params.id :) Thanks for your answer